# My MySQL is broken

Tags: mysql

So I was trying to connect to my MySQL database through Coda 2. I connected, created a database called 'database1' (for example), then I tried to create a table called 'user', but I get this error:

```
MySQL said: Table 'user' is read only
```

I was surprised because it had worked previously with another database. So I went to my xampp files, //xampp/mysql/data/database1/ and then I found our that user.ibd is there. But apparently I need user.obd or something like that. So I said ok, I will just create the database from my server instead. So I when to phpmyadmin, I see that database1 is created but there is no table called 'user'. So I try to create a table and I get this error:

```
#1813 - Tablespace for table '`database1`.`user`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
```

I then I found out I cannot even do much with phpmyadmin from my server. I really need this, I tried unistalling xampp, but it says the file is in use, even though nothing is on it. Please help me, Thank you.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear from the question. Are you manipulating the physical database files directly?

Comment: No I'm not manipulating directly, just from Coda 2, and then from phpmyadmin